# why should I use close method in FlatFileItemWriter in springbatch?

Tags: spring-batch, flatfilereader

why should I use close method in FlatFileItemWriter in springbatch?
or else file date won't be persisted?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch will automatically call the `open`/`update`/`close`/`write` methods when you configure an item writer in a chunk oriented step.

So you don't need to call these lifecycle methods yourself unless you are using the item writer *outside* the scope of a step, in which case you need manually honour the contract implemented by the item writer (`ItemWriter` or `ItemStreamWriter`).